# AppCompat changes in Server 2016 / Win10

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm in the process of upgrading from Server 2008r2 to 2016, but one of the applications needed had to be shimmed in 2008 to get it to work properly.  Specifically

**Virtual Registry: "ADDREDIRECT(HKLM\SOFTWARE^HKCU\SOFTWARE)"**

This worked fine in 2008, but I cannot get it to work in Server 2016 or Win 10.

Has the functionality changed in of the virtual registry feature between versions?  The Logs show the shim being applied, but procMon and the application itself show writes going to HKLM\Software\WOW6432NODE... anyway.